# Facebook apps asked for additional permission

Tags: facebook

I've written a facebook app, and I want to ask users for additional permission by this code:

```
    function loadFanPages()
{
    FB.login(
        function(response) {
            showFanpages();
        }
        , { scope : 'manage_pages' });  
}
```

But I received a message from log:

```
FB.login() called when user is already connected.
```

How can I fix this error? At the first time user use this, I only ask permissions for "email,user_birthday,user_status,user_location"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means the user is already logged in with those permissions granted. If you log out, or remove the permission via facebook, you should see the error disappears. You should make sure you only call that code when you need to so that users won't get this error.

Comment: thank you ^_^ . But I found that I missed `oauth : true` in FB.init, anyway, thank you